# Поиск палиндрома в Haskell

Tags: haskell, функциональное-программирование

При поиске палиндрома, выдает ошибку: isPalindrome :: String ->IO()

```
module Kolt where

  reverse :: [Char] -> [Char]
  reverse [] = []
  reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]


isPalindrome :: String ->IO
isPalindrome y =
  if (reverse "blah" == y)
    then  putStrLn "You are  right"
  else
    putStrLn "You are wrong"
  where y == "blah"
```

Вопрос: Как исправить данный код?

Comment: Здесь много ошибок: от съехавших отступов, до ошибок в алгоритме.

Answer (score 0):

Я поправил код. Так должно заработать, но вы делаете это странным способом.

```
reverse :: [Char] -> [Char]
reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]

isPalindrome :: String -> IO ()
isPalindrome y =
  if (reverse y == y)
  then 
    putStrLn "It is palindrome"
  else
    putStrLn "It isn't palindrome"
```